# Panasonic DMW-FL360L flashgun not firing, blinking Auto Check and Test/Reset lights even after replacing batteries

Tags: troubleshooting, hotshoe-flash, micro-four-thirds, panasonic-lumix

My Panasonic DMW-FL360L has stopped working. I get the blinking Auto Check and Test/Charge lights, which normally indicate that the batteries are depleted; however, even after installing a fully-charged set of batteries, I still get the blinking lights and the flash will not fire. The zoom head on the flash also will not move.

Is there a way I can fix this without having to send the flashgun in for repair?

(The same steps should also apply to the Olympus FL-600R, which is functionally identical.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Follow these steps to soft-reset the flash unit:

1. Ensure that charged batteries are installed and that the unit is off.
2. While holding the **Test/Charge** and **Back Light** buttons, press **On/Off** to turn the unit on, then release all buttons. `D DEL` will appear on the screen.
3. Press **OK**. The Auto Check light will blink three times.
4. Press **On/Off** to turn the unit off, then turn it back on again. The flash should now operate normally.

If this still doesn't work, you may need to contact Panasonic support for repair.